# Source for simple programs in Brainfuck?

Tags: resources, brainfuck

Is there a source where I can get multiple simple programs like addition, factorial, fibonacci and others for the brainfuck programming language?

I know that there has been a question posted before here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554670/tutorials-for-brainfuck

But I would like to have a list of simple programs, short bite-sized programs to get comfortable with the language. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Brainfuck that there is no simple program?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M51AYmDR1Q9UBsoTrGysvuzar2_Hx69Hz14tsQXWV6M/edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the Wiki article had some simple examples of BrainFuck code. [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Examples)

As for Fibonacci, here's a page with some code (not mine, mind you) generating the Fibonacci sequence up to one hundred. [Brainfuck, Fibonacci sequence](http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/bf-source/prog/fibonacci.txt)

Do note that the classic Brainfuck interpreter uses *byte* variables to store memory cells. So if you'd like a factorial, it wouldn't get you much further than 5!.
Nonetheless, I've found an example for you. [Brainfuck, Factorial](http://progopedia.com/example/factorial/18/)

Extra reading: [Simple, and not so simple programs in Brainfuck](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/)

Comment: Now that you've ruined my "implement Fib(n) in brainfuck" interview question, I'm going to have to go with "implement arbitrary-precision integer manipulation in brainfuck".

Comment: @ObscureRobot, yes and Bignums in Brainfuck should clearly be named Bigfuck